# Probablity with special condition

Tags: probability

This is the question -> If the letters of the word ASSASSIN are written in a row at random, the probability that no two S's come together is?

The solution for this is fine and I understand it which goes like this,

[image]

I tried it with a bit different approach in the exam, a bit longer

[image]

and the answer is just the opposite of the desired answer as I have to subtract 1 from my answer, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite of no two Ss occur together is at least two Ss occur together.  Therefore, you would have to consider the following cases:

1. Exactly two Ss occur together, with the other two Ss being separated.
2. Two pairs of adjacent Ss, with the pairs being separated.
3. Three consecutive Ss, with the other S being separated.
4. All four Ss are consecutive.

In your attempt, you only considered the last case.